# How to get nControlID from specific dialog in installshield?

Tags: installshield

I am newbie in working with `installshield`

I need to clear control, there is a system function called `CtrlClear`

[image]

How to get nControlID from specific dialog?, there is no id into properties dialog of control

Appreciate any help.

[image]